# Does the parallel processing changes the complexity for a specific algorithm ?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, complexity-theory, bubble-sort

i hope my question it is in right place , and i also hope it is clear

my question , i want to convert a sequential bubble sort algorithm to a parallel algorithm , my question is , if i convert it , does the complexity still O(n^2) ?

if not , what will the diffrence between sequential algorithms and parallel algorithms ? i know that in parallel the instructions will work in a diffrents cores at a time , but is the diffrent is just the Time ?

maybe my question look like stupied :D but i did not work with parallel processing in the past , so i hope i will get good answers

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Cormen: https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/sample/0262533057chap27.pdf

Yes, supposedly it should change the asymptotic behavior of the algorithm, at least in the sense that whatever the complexity of the algorithm before parallelizing it, it will now boast a "over P", where P is the number of cores/threads/tasks, etc. So it does change the complexity.

A good thing about the CLRS chapter I pointed to above is that it has pseudo-code of algos that might be of interest to you, including a very good merge-sort example. Also, it proposes a model that is practical "Dynamic Multithreading" (look it up), that has been proven very good in practice, first implemented by a spin-off of MIT's Leiserson (the "L" in CLRS), then by Intel (CilkPlus), and finally merged in the main branch of GCC as of 5.1.

This is, of course, theoretical, and actually achieving this speedup of P is very hard practically.